# Problema al subir página a hosting

Tags: php, .htaccess

He diseñado un sistema de Registro Civil; ingresa personas, partidas de nacimientos, matrimonios, difunción etc

En *PHP*, *AJAX*, *JavaScript* y *MySQL*, el sistema contiene paginas como `registrocivil.usuarios`, `registrocivil.personas`, etc,

`registrocivil` es el directorio y usuarios es la pagina en *PHP*.

El problema radica que localmente funciona correctamente, pero al subirlo en el hosting ya no funciona.

Me comuniqué con los del hosting y no me saben ayudar. E

El `.htacces`, al principio, era otro mucho mas extenso y cada vez que deseaba abrir una pagina del sistema me enviaba error 404 (no encontraba la pagina), pero si se sube una página web normal en worpress funciona correctamente, el problema radica que no me redirecciona correctamente bueno eso es lo que creo.

Ahora modifique el `.htacces` por esto

```
Options All -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?ruta=$1
```

Y sigue sin funcionar, aunque ahora si entra al panel, pero ninguna de las opciones funciona, le doy click a cualquiera y la direccion *URL* cambia, pero se queda mostrando el *index* y así con todas las demás, ni siquiera el botón de *salir* funciona, se queda mostrando el *index* también.

Answer (score 0):

El problema podría estar en efecto relacionado a tu `.htaccess`. A grandes rasgos estas líneas indican:

```
# Indica a apache que utilice mod_rewrite (para reescribir las url)
RewriteEngine On

# Usa una regla para reescribir la url de esta forma:
RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?ruta=$1
```

En particular lo que tienes configurado es que, a través de la expresión regular `^([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)$` (que en resumen es cualquier combinación de letras y números - mayúsculas y minúsculas) la petición sea redireccionada al archivo `index.php` colocando la solicitud en el argumento `ruta`.

Por ejemplo, si solicitaras por url `http://ejemplo.com/paginadeejemplo1` el servidor tratará de resolver la solicitud enviándola a `http://ejemplo.com/index.php?ruta=paginadeejemplo1`

Esta estructura funciona bien en Wordpress porque es así como se espera que funcione. Todas las peticiones a wordpress pasan por `index.php` y según los parámetros utilizados en la `Query String`, el sistema discrimina qué debe hacer, qué archivos incluir y cómo resolver la consulta.

Si quisieras imitar este comportamiento, solo como ejemplo en tu archivo `index.php` podrías capturar la variable `ruta` y usarla para incluir tus scripts:

```
// Contenido de archivo index.php
 
$ruta = $_GET['ruta'];  //obtengo la variable "ruta" desde la url

if(!empty($ruta)){
    //Aquí realizas alguna operación que depende de la variable "ruta", 
    //por ejemplo incluir otro archivo.  
}
```

Es solo un ejemplo para darte la idea.

Si **NO** quieres adaptar tu código al `.htaccess` del servidor, debes editar entonces el archivo `.htaccess` y cambiar la `RewriteRule` por algo que satisfaga la estructura que esperas, y hacer que se relacione la url con tu estructura de archivos.

Recomiendo que busques documentación y ejemplos sobre [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html), en especial con `RewriteRule` y `RewriteCond` y pruebes algunas variantes para que vayas adaptándolo a tus necesidades. Y (aunque me imagino que ya lo hiciste) revisar tu configuración local (donde sí funciona) para que puedas ver dónde está la gran diferencia que evita que funcione en el servidor externo.

Comment: Mira lo que me djaron @RVera +Rvera

Answer (score 0):

Gracias @Rvera yo soy desarrollador novato asi que no sabia que debia modificar el .htaccess. Mi codigo de ruteo es este

```
if(isset($_GET["ruta"])){
  if($_GET["ruta"] == "inicio" ||
     $_GET["ruta"] == "usuarios" ||
     $_GET["ruta"] == "crear-acta-defunciones" ||
     $_GET["ruta"] == "salir"){
    include "modulos/".$_GET["ruta"].".php";

  }
```

Y acabo de revisar y desde mi hosting me han derivado a un subdominio y han creado un .htaccess para que no cree conflicto con el de worpress y este es el .htacces ahora funciona inicio pero cuando modifico para las demas enlaces no funciona no se nada de .htacces

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/registro/index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /registro/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Esto no es una respuesta a tu problema, puedes editar tu pregunta añadiendo lo que sabes o hacer otra